# How to add "filter" to this Google Analytics query?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to access Google Analytics API.

How to add a filter that pulls only the data for:
`ga:campaign` contains "tv"
**and**
`ga:sourceMedium` contains "Google / CPC"

Please, see my current request:

```
metrics_columns = [
  {expression: 'ga:transactions'},
  {expression: 'ga:adCost'}
];

dimensions_rows = [{
  name: 'ga:campaign'
}];

date_filters = [{
  startDate: 'today',
  endDate: 'today',
}];

sort = [{
  fieldName: 'ga:transactions',
  sortOrder: "DESCENDING"
}];

var req = {
  reportRequests: [{
    viewId: viewID,
    dateRanges: date_filters,
    metrics: metrics_columns,
    dimensions: dimensions_rows,
  }],
};
```

Comment: Or any filter, please?

Comment: Ok, I found it. Everything is here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics

And the logic is: if {dimensionName} {operator} {expressions}
    return the dimension